# What is the difference between yarn run and npm start?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package-managers, npm-start

Is `yarn run` intended to be the equivalent of `npm start`?

Comment: to make matters more confusing, yarn start == yarn run start

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It seems `yarn run start` is the equivalent of `npm start`, which runs the script inside the `start` field of the `script` field in `package.json`

Comment: `yarn start` also runs the `start` script from package.json.

Answer (score 66):

Few things to understand:

**npm:** run command **is mandatory** to execute user defined scripts.
**yarn:** run command is **not mandatory** to execute user defined scripts.

**start** command is not a user defined script name, so you may not need to specify run command to execute it.

So, all the below commands work similar!

- `npm start`
- `npm run start`
- `yarn start`
- `yarn run start`

If you have a user defined script named **'app'**:

- `npm app` **(Does not work!)**
- `npm run app` **(Works!)**
- `yarn app` **(Works!)**
- `yarn run app`  **(Works!)**

*Note: By default start runs **node server.js** in case not explicitly defined.*

Comment: The default behaviour you specified is misleading.

Comment: Default behaviour is also mentioned in the doc similarly https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html

Comment: **run** is not required for `yarn run` unless the script's name is the same a yarn sub-command (e.g. "run" would need `yarn run run` which is weird and might want to be avoided).

Answer (score 19):

`npm start` is a shortcut for `npm run start`

Now in terms of **running scripts** from `package.json`, all these are equivalent:

`npm run start`
`npm start`
`yarn run start`
`yarn start`

`npm run myscript`
*`npm myscript` **this is an error***
`yarn run myscript`
`yarn myscript`

This is because `run` *is not* mandatory command for `yarn`, but *it is* for `npm`.

---

#### Bonus

`npr start` - OK
`npr myscript` - OK

Put *this* file somewhere in `PATH`, eg. `%localappdata%\Programs\Git\cmd`

`npr.cmd`

```
npm run %*
```

Answer (score 1):

`yarn run` is similar to `npm run`, they can be used to run the scripts in `package.json`.

For npm, **you can leave out `run` when run the npm lifecycle scripts (`test`, `start`, `restart`, and `stop`)**, but these scripts maybe have extra effect. For example, `npm start` will run `node server.js` if the "scripts" object does not define a "start" property in `package.json`. see the doc [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script). **You can't run script with other name leaving out `run`.**

For yarn, **you can leave out `run` for all the scripts in `package.json`**, but if your script name is same as yarn built-in cli commands, **the built-in cli commands will have preference over your scripts**. doc [yarn run](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run).

**So the best way to run scripts in package.json: never leave out `run`.**