# Cannot use own API routes with "yarn run dev"

Tags: javascript, port, yarnpkg

I am working on my app, and while I use `yarn run dev` I cannot make API calls to the API routes defined by me. The app runs on port 3000, but the server on 3500. If I hardcode the "3500" into the API call, it works, like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3500/api/config').then(r => r.json());
```

if I leave it like this it doesn't work:

```
fetch('/api/config').then(r => r.json());
```

If I deploy the app online or if I use `yarn run dev-server`, there is no problem, it works. Is this a normal thing to happen? Should I try to fix this, or is it something normal?

Comment: view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619443/6651840)

Comment: What port is the yarn run dev-server running?

Comment: is running on 3000

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you do

```js
fetch('/api/config').then(r => r.json());
```

It will try to request `localhost:3000/api/config`, and that doesn't exist because your server is running on 3500 and not 3000. When you hardcode the port the request will be sent to the correct port, so it will work.

Comment: Yes, it will work locally, but if I leave it like this, when I deploy live it won't work

Comment: @BogosRobert Use a variable to change the server URL, if it's development then set it to `localhost:3500`, if it's production set it to your production URL.

Comment: This is a solution, but not such a good one , because I would need to declare that variable in all the files that I want to make api calls , I was looking for a more solid solution

Comment: You can use a global variable, for example `window.serverURL`.